# Convert SQL server datetime to SSIS String using SQL only?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting a datetime column from SqlServer (SS). I want it to appear as a "String" column to SSIS so that I can directly fit it into an SSIS string. After that, I want to loop over this column with a Foreach loop and assign each row to a SSIS string called "str_SSIS". So, I tried `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), MyDatetimeColumn, 121)` and dumped it into a result set.

But, SSIS complains that the type of the vaue being assigned to variable str_SSIS differs from the current variable type.

Now, I also get the error - Error: ForEach Variable Mapping number 1 to variable "strMyString" cannot be applied.

Why could this be happening and how do I fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably dont need the foreach for this. Components on a dataflow are applied to *every* record. So if you simply use a source, then a data conversion/ derived column with a cast, it will give you the result set you need. Also your `str_SSIS` variable would have to be an *array* of strings(object) since you're making it a result set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the source in SSIS because SSIS persists data types, so if it's changed, the SSIS doesn't know and there's the error you have.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood this correctly you have an execute sql task which outputs multiple records with string date values and you want to iterate through the values to use as filter for your dataflow source task,to do this you need 2 variables,an object type variable lets say obj_ssis and second string variable str_ssis.step1:in execute sql task change the result set to full result set and in resultset tab add the object variable.2)in foreach loop select Foreach ADO Enumerator and in ADO object source variable select "obj_SSIS" then in variable mapping select str_SSIS string variable and now you should have required values in the string value